# how to link django url to decoupled react app

Tags: reactjs, django

I have built my app with django as the backend and react as the frontend. I want to keep the two decoupled. However, I have an use case where I want to link from django to my react app.

The frontend and backend will be hosted on different domains.
While sending a password reset email, I need to link to a react page.

The url is `localhost:3000/reset/{code_here}/`
I need to include this URL in an email (from the backend).

I am not sure of what the best way to do this is.
Should I hardcode the URL into my emails? Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Hardcoding can be done cause your url won't be changing like daily or monthly. Once your frontend is deployed to some address you can change that url and it will work.

Comment: is this the recommended way? thanks for your reply!

Comment: As you said, two applications are decoupled and they will be deployed on different addresses, this seems the only way for your backend to know where your frontend is (i guess).

Comment: thanks! I might as well as accept this as an answer!

Comment: also, do you recommend storing the frontend URL in the django settings module, so that we can easily change the URLs when the app is deployed later?

Comment: playing with settings.py may create some error in your application if you accidentally delete or change something by mistake. So better store it in variable in your reset link view or you can even use the django admin panel to do so, but then you have to create database and table for it.